# Adding a png to clipboard in android

Tags: android, png, clipboard

i have following code:

```
        File imageFile = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ContentResolver theContent = getContentResolver();
        Uri  imageUri = theContent.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(),"image", imageUri);

        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

I only see the path in the `clipboard` not the `image` itself, i think it must be possible to see the `image` because when you take a screenshot you see the image in the clipboard. Maybe it's only with a bitmap if you know how to pass a bitmap to the clipboard please tell.
If any one can suggest a solution i will be very thankful.

Comment: Is your problem is solved.I have the same issue. Do u have any solution of this problem, pasting path not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Android Clipboard works slightly different from its counterparts like the Mac OS PasteBoard and Windows's Clipboard. Mac and Windows approach is to physically store contents like Image/Binary, RTF, File references, etc., so data can be shared within the system. The Android clipboard can store only text (and can deal with HTML since Jelly Bean). Other types are represented by a Content Provider URI pointing to the actual data. It is job of the App receiving the URI to retrieve its contents (via ContentResolver) and treat the incoming data accordingly.